# Change input value with javascript array path

Tags: javascript

Greetings dear community,

I'm wondering on how to change a input value with javascript using a array path, what i mean with array path is the array that you can extract from chrome console with the code below:

```
crumb = function(node) {
    var idOrClass = (node.id && "#"+node.id) || 
                    (""+node.classList && (" "+node.classList).replace(/ /g, "."));
    return node.tagName.toLowerCase() + idOrClass;
};
crumbPath = function(node) {
    return node.parentNode 
            ? crumbPath(node.parentNode).concat(crumb(node)) 
            : [];
};
crumbPath($0);
```

This will give me something like this:

```
[
    "html.dj_webkit.dj_chrome.dj_contentbox", 
    "body.oneui.idx_dojo_1_9.dj_chrome.dj_chrome70", 
    "div#jsel_table", 
    "div#jsel_container", 
    "div#jsel_div1", 
    "div#jsel_div1_toolbar", 
    "div#widget_jsel_div1_viewDropDown", 
    "div.dijitReset.dijitInputField.dijitInputContainer", 
    "input"
]
```

Is it possible to change the value using this array?

Kindest regards

Comment: I'm confused, why would you want to change a value using that array? Why not just change a value of an element using something like this: ```document.getElementById('element_id').value = 'new value';``` ?

Comment: Because i need that specific value and sadly i'm not the one who set the base name of the div so i need to path it

Comment: I don't see how you'll do this then as you're blind to what the element's selector name/id/class is that you need to update.